# "for" cycle in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces, jspx

I simply need to perform a very basic `for` cycle in JSF/ICEFaces, basically rendering column numbers

Something like the following pseudo-code

```
for(int i=0; i<max; i++)
{
   <td>#{i}</td>
}
```

the `<c:forEach>` tag iterates over collections, but I don't want to make my backing bean more complex returning a stupid collection of integers.

Do you know a shorter and smarter way?

Thank you

Comment: JSTL's `c:forEach` is okay for simple stuff like this. However, due to the rendering nature of it, you can easily get into [trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4154930/1009867). I recommend using `ui:repeat` instead.

Comment: I second @geca's reply. `<ui:repeat>` takes a collection as a value and iterates over each element, inside you can write any markup you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<ui:repeat>` tag is what you should really use. The JSTL tags operate outside of the JSF Lifecycle. Cay Horstman has a JSF coursewhich discusses this fact: [ui:repeat and Handling 
Variable-Length Data](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/jsf/jsf2/JSF2-Looping.pdf).

There are a couple of solutions below which demonstrate some flexibility. You could do something like this:

```
<ui:param name="max" value="5"/>
<ui:repeat var="i" value="#{indexBean.values}" size="#{max}" >
 <tr><td>#{i}</td></tr>
</ui:repeat>
```

The maximum number of rows is determined by a a `<ui:parameter>` named `max`. This is not required, but does demonstrate flexibility. Alternatively you could use something like:

```
<ui:param name="max" value="5"/>
<ui:repeat var="i" value="#{indexBean.rowNumbers(max)}">
 <tr><td>#{i}</td></tr>
</ui:repeat>
```

The backing bean code is the following:

```
@ManagedBean
public class IndexBean {

public List<Integer> getValues() {
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        values.add(i);
    }
    return values;
}

public List<Integer> rowNumbers(final int max) {
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        values.add(i);
    }
    return values;
}
}
```

Comment: Please note I have opened a bug [JAVASERVERFACES-2425](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2425) on the size attribute. The size VDL document does not indicate that the value includes the end element for example `size=5` prints out 0-5 instead of 0-4 which would be five elements. I expect this will be corrected in 2.2.

Comment: The behavior is fixed in 2.1.9+

Answer (score 12):

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="#{someBean.max}">
             <td>#{i}</td>      
 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Yea definitely correct ;);) I thought the items property was required, I just tried the code and worked fine :D :D

Answer (score 4):

I suggest thinking at a higher level of abstraction, not in terms of rendering HTML tags, but in terms of using a component that does what you need. For example, Primefaces' datatable supports [dynamic columns](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf), which should be capable of replacing your on-page iteration logic.

Comment: Surely a wise answer, but what I need to do in my case is really too simple to think about a smarter design. Anyway thanks and upvote!

Answer (score 1):

Simple example using ui repeat

```
<ul>
    <ui:repeat var="entry" value="${tourBean.tour.highlights}">
        <li class="pb-1">#{entry}</li>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

with rich faces data table you can dynamically generate columns headers and values