# Message bundle intermittently not rendering correct

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jstl

In my application I am trying to get labels out of a message bundle.
However rather then use constant key values I am using variables

```
<c:forEach var="emailAddress" items="${emailAddresses}">
...
<c:set var="labelKey" value="Contact_Label_${emailAddress.type}"/>
...
<h:outputText value="#{faces_translations[labelKey]}"/>
...
</c:forEach>
```

Most of the time this works correctly, but every so often when a page is
loaded some of the label are not processed correctly and the following
message is displayed:

```
???Contact_Label_???
```

It looks like the email.type does not return a value, however I added some
debug code to print out the value of email.type by including

```
${emailAddress.type}
```

and saw that a value was returned.

Another thing I tried was to remove the value everytime before setting it
again inside the loop using . This resulted in the following
exception. I verified that I had the tag library included in the WAR file
(jstl-api-1.2.jar and jstl-impl-1.2.jar as well as javax.faces-2.1.7).

```
<c:remove> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core,
but no tag was defined for name: remove
```

Both these issues are really baffling. The label works most of the time,
but not consistently. The tag is defined in the included library, but cannot be found.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154841/mixing-jsf-tags-with-jstl-tags-gives-strange-results gives some info. Maybe `'${labelKey}'  might work.

Comment: You're really not supposed to mix JSTL/JSF2.0. How about using ui:repeat instead?

Answer (score 1):

JSF UI components and tag handlers like JSTL doesn't run in sync. JSTL runs when the JSF view is to be built. The result is a JSF component tree *without* any tag handlers like `<c:xxx>` and `<f:xxx>`. JSF UI components runs when the JSF view needs to generate HTML for the HTTP response. That very same JSF view can be reused multiple times in subsequent HTTP requests as long as you're interacting with the same view by returning `null` or `void` on POST actions (like as you should use a `@ViewScoped` bean). It is not true that JSTL tags runs on every single HTTP request. That's most likely where it went wrong in your case.

Rather use JSF UI components if you want consistent render-time behaviour while reusing the same view. Your construct can be replaced as follows:

```html
<ui:repeat var="emailAddress" value="#{emailAddresses}">
    ...
    <ui:param name="labelKey" value="Contact_Label_#{emailAddress.type}" />
    ...
    <h:outputText value="#{faces_translations[labelKey]}" />
    ...
</ui:repeat>
```

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)