# how to display h:panelGroup based on a condition

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jstl

In my problem, I have to display `h:panelGroup` based on a condition. For this `h:panelGroup`, the   `rendered` attribute has already been set.

```
 <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty program.categories}">
    <li>
        <strong>Category: </strong> 
        <h:outputLabel value="#{not empty program.categories ? 'A':'N/A'}"/>
    </li>
 </h:panelGroup>
```

now I am trying to keep a condition like the code below:

```
<c:if test="${program.distTypeName != 'X' || program.distTypeName != 'Y' || program.distTypeName != 'Z'}">

<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty program.categories}">
    <li>
        <strong>Category: </strong> 
        <h:outputLabel value="#{not empty program.categories ? 'A':'N/A'}" />
    </li>
</h:panelGroup>
```

but this is not working. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Basically, if the `disType` is not in x,y,z then I need to display the `h:panelGroup`.

How do we test `not in` condition with jstl tags?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-jsf-components/4870557#4870557) will help you.

Comment: but how can use rendered atrribute in my scenario.. <c:if> is not working..i should check condition only for this h:panelGroup..not for the entire form. please suggest.

Comment: Move the `<c:if>` condition inside the `rendered` attribute of `<h:panelGroup>`

Comment: Provided that `distTypeName` is an enum or a string, the code posted so far is perfectly legit when considered standalone (e.g. when that's the sole content of `<h:body>`). Isn't that code *actually* inside an `<ui:repeat>` or `<h:dataTable>` or so? If so, then this question duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442380/jstl-cif-inside-a-jsf-hdatatable Please take that into account in your future questions (the code posted so far should reproduce the problem when interpreted as the sole content of `<h:body>`). See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Answer (score 0):

JSTL tags and JSF tags are not synchronous. JSTL tags run in build time while JSF tags run in render time. That is why you see a strange behavior. You should use JSF `rendered` attribute instead of `c:if`

Furthermore, char comparison also works differently from Java. Chars behave like String in EL expressions which means `!=` operator does not give proper results for `String` comparison.

```
<c:if test="${program.distTypeName != 'X' || program.distTypeName != 'Y' || program.distTypeName != 'Z'}">
```

Above `c:if` statement can be converted to rendered attribute like

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{program.distTypeName.compareTo('X') != 0 || program.distTypeName.compareTo('Y') != 0 || program.distTypeName.compareTo('Z') != 0}">
```

or ASCII representations of characters can also be used here if `distTypeName` is a `char`.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{program.distTypeName ne 88 || program.distTypeName ne 89 || program.distTypeName ne 90}">
```

**Related Post**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4154930/892994

Comment: This is likely not the cause. The code as OP postes so far is perfectly legit. This would only cause problems if the code posted so far is actually inside a JSF repeater component such as `<ui:repeat>` or `<h:dataTable>`, but nothing in the question indicates that. The bean name `#{program}` is already a big hint that it represents an entity not a backing bean.