# How to put user-typed values into a List of Strings?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, foreach

My current JSF version is 2.1 and I'd like to find a short solution for putting user-typed `String`s into a single `List`. In the managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean{

    private List<String> values;

    public void List<Integer> getIdentifiers(){
        List<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //...
        return lst;
    }

    //GET, SET, OTHER STUFF

}
```

and markup:

```
<c:forEach items="#{myBean.identifiers}" var="id">
    <h:inputText value="__WHAT?__" id="input#{id}" />
</c:forEach>
```

I need to put each value, typed by user into the `inputText`s into the `values` `List<String>` . How can I do that or is it possible at all?

UPD: I need to do that exactly with `<c:forEach>` loop because it's possible that I should add some other input fields, like `rich:calendar` which are going to be rendered as follows:

```
<c:forEach items="#{myBean.identifiers}" var="id">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="__calendar_needed__">
            <rich:calendar />
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="__input_needed__">
             <h:inputText value="__WHAT?__" id="input#{id}" />
        </c:when>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using JSF 2, you can use the [`<ui:repeat>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html) tag as a replacement for `<c:forEach>` (because [mixing JSTL with JSF can lead to strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4154930/1003142)).

Also, you can directly set the `value` attribute to point to the `values` collection in the bean (of course, you have to provide the corresponding accessors). Each object from the collection will be referred as `item`:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.values}" var="item">
    <h:inputText value="#{item}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: No, I need to iterate over the collection returned by `getIdentifiers()`.

Comment: Hmm... but how can I replcae `<c:choose>` in a JSF way? Is it possible?

Comment: You can replace `<c:choose>` with the `rendered` attribute for each of the visual components. The `rendered` attribute needs a `boolean` expression to denote whether or not the component should be displayed on the screen.

Comment: Yes, it will. And I need to render the `getIdentifiers().size()` inputs first and when the user filled the inputs and submit the parent form I need to put the values into `values` List.

Comment: When initializing the `values` list set it to be same-sized as the size of the `getIdentifiers()` result. This way the desired amount of inputs will be rendered on the screen.

Comment: I got that, thank you.